# Yii2 Call api method from backend controllers

Tags: rest, api, yii2

I have implemented API based on advanced template following Yii Rest API documentation. And I want to call API methods from backend controllers. Is it possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: If you mean call those API methods and process its results, you have to use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I finally found a solution.

My Yii2 application has advanced template. I've created api module.

So app has 3 endpoints

- api
- backend
- frontend

And I wanted to call api methods from backend or frontend, It's not important.

So the main goal here that api is the **module**. You can read about this [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html#using-modules)

In **backend/config/main.php**

```
'modules' => [
    'api' => [
        'basePath' => '@api/modules/v1',
        'class' => 'api\modules\v1\Module'
    ]
],
```

And then for example

**in backend/UserController/indexAction**

```
$res = Yii::$app->runAction('api/user/index');
```

That how it works. Hope it will help to someone.

Answer (score 1):

A way could be this .

Assuming that you rest controller is in frontend

In your backend application config you could create an additional 'UrlManager' component name eg: urlManagerForRest

```
return [
  'components' => [
      'urlManager' => [
          // here is your backend URL rules
      ],
      'urlManagerForRest' => [
          'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
          'baseUrl' => 'http://your_path/frontend/web/index.php',
          'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
          'showScriptName' => false,
      ],

  ],
];
```

Then you should invoke following to compose  URL:

```
Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontEnd->createUrl();
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) for testing your api.
first download your version of postman then choose your method. then determine your inputs and your url. and finally press send button.
your url might be like

```
http://yourdomain.com/backend/web/index.php?r=yourController/yourAction
```

that `yourdomain.com` is your domain and `yourController` are controller and `yourAction` are your action.