# Passing input parameters to API

Tags: rest, api, soap, yii2

I am creating a Yii2 project. But instead of writing the logics in the controller I am trying to call APIs from the controller as described here:

[yii2-call-api-method-from-backend-controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175117/yii2-call-api-method-from-backend-controllers)

Can I pass input parameters to the called API ? If so pls mention how to.
Thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean you want to `pass` or `post` data along with the API call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add get parameters during api call, try:

```
$res = Yii::$app->runAction('api/user/get_call',['a'=>'sth','b' => 'sth_else']);
```

To add post parameters is a bit trickier. You have to set body parameters before call:

```
Yii::$app->request->setBodyParams(['a' => 'sth', 'b' => 'sth_else']);
$res = Yii::$app->runAction('api/user/post_call');
```